# syntec issue: opening link report with parameters in a new browse window.

Tags: javascript, reporting-services

```
"javascript:void(window.open('http://myservername/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fRPTS%    2fTrend_Detail&rs:Command=Render
&root_cause="+Fields!Root_Cause.Value+"
&level_0="+Fields!Level_0_Results.Value+"
&level_1="+Fields!Level_1_Results.Value+"
&level_2="+Fields!Level_2_Results.Value+"
&year_month_nbr="+Fields!year_month_nbr.Value+"
&IssueSource="+Join(Parameters!IssueSource.Value,"&IssueSource=")"+
'))"
```

If i leave the &IssueSource="+Join(Parameters!IssueSource.Value,"&IssueSource=")"+
 line out i get a message: user-defined value for the report parameter 'IssueSource'.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are off at the end. Try

```
&IssueSource="+Join(Parameters!IssueSource.Value,"&IssueSource=")+
"'))"
```